# error C2039: 'binder2nd': is not a member of 'std' - Compiler Error with Eigen

Tags: eigen

I became the following Error during the Compile with (Debug/x64) in Visual Studio.

```
1>c:\users\ui\desktop\eigen-eigen-323c052e1731\eigen\src/Core/functors/StlFunctors.h(78): error C2039: 'binder2nd': is not a member of 'std'
1>  c:\users\ui\desktop\eigen-eigen-323c052e1731\eigen\src/Core/arch/CUDA/Half.h(614): note: see declaration of 'std'
1>c:\users\ui\desktop\eigen-eigen-323c052e1731\eigen\src/Core/functors/StlFunctors.h(78): error C2065: 'binder2nd': undeclared identifier
1>c:\users\ui\desktop\eigen-eigen-323c052e1731\eigen\src/Core/functors/StlFunctors.h(78): error C2974: 'Eigen::internal::functor_traits': invalid template argument for 'T', type expected
1>  c:\users\ui\desktop\eigen-eigen-323c052e1731\eigen\src/Core/util/XprHelper.h(147): note: see declaration of 'Eigen::internal::functor_traits'
1>c:\users\ui\desktop\eigen-eigen-323c052e1731\eigen\src/Core/functors/StlFunctors.h(78): error C2988: unrecognizable template declaration/definition
1>c:\users\ui\desktop\eigen-eigen-323c052e1731\eigen\src/Core/functors/StlFunctors.h(78): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '>'
1>c:\users\ui\desktop\eigen-eigen-323c052e1731\eigen\src/Core/functors/StlFunctors.h(78): error C2059: syntax error: '>'
1>c:\users\ui\desktop\eigen-eigen-323c052e1731\eigen\src/Core/functors/StlFunctors.h(79): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '{'
1>c:\users\ui\desktop\eigen-eigen-323c052e1731\eigen\src/Core/functors/StlFunctors.h(79): error C2447: '{': missing function header (old-style formal list?)
1>c:\users\ui2\desktop\eigen-eigen-323c052e1731\eigen\src/Core/functors/StlFunctors.h(82): error C2039: 'binder1st': is not a member of 'std'
1>  c:\users\ui\desktop\eigen-eigen-323c052e1731\eigen\src/Core/arch/CUDA/Half.h(614): note: see declaration of 'std'
1>c:\users\ui\desktop\eigen-eigen-323c052e1731\eigen\src/Core/functors/StlFunctors.h(82): error C2065: 'binder1st': undeclared identifier
1>c:\users\ui\desktop\eigen-eigen-323c052e1731\eigen\src/Core/functors/StlFunctors.h(82): error C2974: 'Eigen::internal::functor_traits': invalid template argument for 'T', type expected
1>  c:\users\ui\desktop\eigen-eigen-323c052e1731\eigen\src/Core/functors/StlFunctors.h(78): note: see declaration of 'Eigen::internal::functor_traits'
1>c:\users\ui\desktop\eigen-eigen-323c052e1731\eigen\src/Core/functors/StlFunctors.h(82): error C2988: unrecognizable template declaration/definition
1>c:\users\ui\desktop\eigen-eigen-323c052e1731\eigen\src/Core/functors/StlFunctors.h(82): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '>'
1>c:\users\ui\desktop\eigen-eigen-323c052e1731\eigen\src/Core/functors/StlFunctors.h(82): error C2059: syntax error: '>'
1>c:\users\ui\desktop\eigen-eigen-323c052e1731\eigen\src/Core/functors/StlFunctors.h(83): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '{'
1>c:\users\ui\desktop\eigen-eigen-323c052e1731\eigen\src/Core/functors/StlFunctors.h(83): error C2447: '{': missing function header (old-style formal list?)
1>CCalcInverse.cpp(94): warning C4267: 'initializing': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
```

I have only include the Header File from Eigen and compile.

Comment: If you put some code which causes this error, people will appreciate. :)

Comment: What MSVC version do you use? What is the value of the macros `__cplusplus` and `_MSC_VER`?

Comment: Thanks for the reaction. I use Visual Studio 2015. But I have no code. I have only the the following includes: #include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <unsupported/Eigen/NonLinearOptimization>
#include <unsupported/Eigen/NumericalDiff>

Comment: __cplusplus = 199711L ; _MSC_VER = 1900

Comment: If I include the Eigen files in .h file, there are no Error. But if I include this in cpp-File, i became this error

Comment: Does it compile, if you manually `#include <functional>` before including Eigen? With c++98, `binder2nd` should still exist.

Comment: It works now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it seems to be a bug of VS2019, I switched the `c++ language standard` back and forth from `/std:c++latest` to `std:c++20` to `std:c++17`, and then the issue is gone.

I guess by doing this some compiler macro is cleared.